# How to Install system (Windows 10) fonts for use with rinohtype/sphinx?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, rinohtype

First I'm very much a beginner with Python/Sphinx/rinohtype.

I'm trying to figure out how to install fonts for use with rinohtype/Sphinx, rinohtype installs some fonts but I'm looking to use the fonts installed on my Windows 10 system, like Arial, I've trawled through the rinohtype docs looking for guidance but have been unable to figure this out.

Edit: output is as follows:

```
rinohtype 0.5.3 (2021-06-16)  Copyright (c) Brecht Machiels and contributors
This program comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. Its use is subject
to the terms of the GNU Affero General Public License version 3.
rendering...
References cache read from C:\Users\marjohloo\Documents\Sphinx\Test\_build\rinoh\lxr.rtc
Typeface 'Arial' is not installed; searching Google Fonts.
-> not found: please check the typeface name (case-sensitive!)

Exception occurred:
  File "c:\users\marjohloo\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\rinoh\resource.py", line 42, in parse_string
    raise ResourceNotFound(cls, resource_name, entry_point_name)
rinoh.resource.ResourceNotFound: (<class 'rinoh.font.Typeface'>, 'ARIAL', 'arial')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rinohtype does not yet support using system fonts ([issue #75](https://github.com/brechtm/rinohtype/issues/75)). Font support neither is properly documented yet, unfortunately (but this is a start). Your font options are currently:

1. Free fonts packaged for rinohtype and [published on PyPI](https://pypi.org/search/?q=rinoh-typeface) (*rinoh-typeface-** packages)
2. Any of the 1000+ fonts available on [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/). If a typeface specified in your style sheet is not installed, rinohtype will search the font on Google Fonts, download and install it. Note that the typeface name in your style sheet needs to match the font name on Google Fonts exactly (case-sensitive).
3. The [Microsoft Core Fonts for the Web](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_fonts_for_the_Web) are available as packages on PyPI. See [rinoh-mscorefonts](https://github.com/brechtm/rinoh-mscorefonts#readme) for the full list.
4. Create your own Python package to make fonts available to rinohtype. Example included below.

You can list the installed fonts using [rinoh](http://www.mos6581.org/rinohtype/master/rinoh.html):

```
rinoh --list-fonts
```

Specifically, for Arial, you can consider using [TeX Gyre Heros](https://pypi.org/project/rinoh-typeface-texgyreheros/) font instead. The [TeX Gyre](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/tex-gyre/index_html) font collection offers free alternatives for a number of other popular fonts, including Times, Helvetica (Arial), Courier and Palatino.

If you want the real thing instead, you can create your own font package for Arial. You can use [rinoh-typeface-carlito](https://github.com/brechtm/rinoh-typeface-carlito) as a template for that.

If you're using Sphinx, you do not need to create and install a Python package. You can create this `fonts.py` file and import it in your Sphinx `conf.py` (after `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('.'))`):

```py
from pathlib import Path

from rinoh import register_typeface
from rinoh.font import Typeface
from rinoh.font.opentype import OpenTypeFont


FONTS_DIR = Path(r'C:\Windows\Fonts')


def otf(filename, **kwargs):
    return OpenTypeFont(str(FONTS_DIR / filename), **kwargs)


arial = Typeface('Arial',
                 otf('arial.ttf'),
                 otf('arialbd.ttf'),
                 otf('ariali.ttf'),
                 otf('arialbi.ttf'),
        )
register_typeface('arial', arial)
```

I'm sure this is not straightforward for anyone who's not familiar with Python. Let me know if you need more info. This situation should improve as rinohtype matures, however.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I successfully am using the font I want (actually Calibri) for other reference I adapted the code above saving as font_calibri.py alongside my sphinx conf.py file and then in my conf.py uncommented a few lines and imported my new file so it ended up looking like this: 

    `import os # uncomment`

    `import sys # uncomment`

    `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('.')) # uncomment`

    `import font_calibri # add`

Comment: This is so useful, please feed this back in the documentation!